# USQL reading last n days when file name pattern does not have day part

Tags: u-sql, azure-analysis-services

In data lake I have file names with pattern yyyyMM_data.csv. Now I want to read previous 3 days data. I am using below code -

```
DECLARE @ReportDate DateTime= DateTime.Parse("05/08/2017");
DECLARE @FeatureSummaryInput string=@"/FolderPath/{InputFileDate:yyyy}{InputFileDate:MM}_data.csv";

@FeaturedUsed =
    EXTRACT Id string,InputFileDate DateTime
    FROM @FeatureSummaryInput
    USING Extractors.Csv(silent : true, skipFirstNRows : 1);

@FeaturedUsed=
    SELECT *
           FROM @FeaturedUsed
    WHERE InputFileDate BETWEEN @ReportDate.AddDays(-3) AND @ReportDate;
```

If I run above code it runs with empty input. Please let me know if I am missing something. Why it is not reading correct file?

It seems like we need to must have "day" in file name pattern to work this.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly I am missing something but, as you cast `InputFileDate` to `DateTime` it defaults to the first of the month, as no day is specified.  For your test `ReportDate` set to `05/08/2017`, your `WHERE` clause basically evaluates to `Between 2017-08-02 And 2017-08-05`, which will never be true.

Where do you expect the day element to come in with your files structured as `yyyyMM`?